# Can I use JavascriptExecutor with Appium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, appium

I'm trying to click some mobile element (`Appium`) with `JavascriptExecutor`.
It throws `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException`:
(see below)
My code is very simple.
`JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`
The `element` above is OK.
So my question is:
Can I use `JavascriptExecutor`with `Appium` mobile elements and if yes - what should I change using the `JavascriptExecutor`?

`unknown error (An unknown server-side error occurred. status='false'. Failed to complete internal method: 'hybridRunJavascript args: [, 0, result = null;resultType = null;resultMessage = null;function getPathToWithSuffix(element,suffix) {if (element.tagName.toUpperCase() == "HTML".toUpperCase())return '//html'+suffix;if (element===document.body)return '//html/body[1]'+suffix;var ix= 0;var siblings= element.parentNode.childNodes;for (var i= 0; i<siblings.length; i++) {var sibling= siblings[i];if (sibling===element)return getPathToWithSuffix(element.parentNode,'/'+element.tagName.toLowerCase()+'['+(ix+1)+']'+suffix);if (sibling.nodeType===1 && sibling.tagName===element.tagName)ix++;}}function runScriptResultWrapper(element){if((typeof element === undefined) || element == null){result = null;resultMessage = null;return;}else if (typeof element === 'string' || element instanceof String){result = element;resultType = "string";resultMessage = null;return;}else if (typeof element === 'number' || element instanceof Number){if(element % 1 === 0){resultType = "int"}else{resultType = "float";}result = element;resultMessage = null;return;}else if (typeof element === 'boolean' || element instanceof Boolean){resultType = "boolean";result = element;resultMessage = null;return;}var paths = [];if(element.constructor === Array || element.length > 0){var elements = element;for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {var elementPath = getPathToWithSuffix(elements[i],"");paths[i] = elementPath;}resultMessage = null;}else if(!element.parentNode){resultType = "object";result = element;resultMessage = null;return;}else{resultMessage = null;paths[0] = getPathToWithSuffix(element,"");}resultType = null;result = {value: paths};};var userFunc = function() {var arguments = new Array();arguments[0]=document.evaluate("(//*[@resource-id='text' or @id='text'])[1]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();;arguments[0].click();;};result = null;var temp_result = userFunc();if(result == null) {result = temp_result;} runScriptResultWrapper(result);]', details: Failed to run javascript '': null)  (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds`

Comment: Your attempted command can be use using appium if you are in web context, this command will not execute on native context

Comment: So actually JavascriptExecutor not supported by Appium. OK, thanks.

Comment: Supported, but it's depend on which command do you want to run.. :)

Comment: For example such basic command as click. But I mean working on a native context, not web

Comment: Then you can't, because JavaScript execute only on web not native

Comment: While Appium works mainly on native context....
So we can simply say that Appium does not support JavascriptExecutor.
That's it.

Answer (score 2):

In [Appium](http://appium.io) you can use [executeScript() method](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) only for running [Mobile Commands](http://Execute%20Mobile%20Command)

like:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("direction", "down");
params.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
driver.executeScript("mobile: swipe", params);
```

So my expectation is that you should use [`element.click()` method](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html#click--) instead.

If you have problems with "normal" click - you can consider using [SeeTest - Appium Extension Click command](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Click) which can perform multiple clicks and locate elements using [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)

Comment: I do have problems with the regular `element.click()` method otherwise I would not try using the `JavascriptExecutor` and would not ask this question.
I will learn the `SeeTest` above and see if it can solve my problems.
Thank you!

Comment: Most probably you have wrong locator or something like that, "click()" method should work just fine, do you have any client/server logs? If yes - add them to your question

Comment: No, the locator is OK, the problem is that the element appears to not be clickable so clicking on it with regular `element.click()` works but not works good. It takes a long time and not stable (sometimes timeout occur before the element receives the click)

Comment: @DmitriT I was not aware that Javascript was only available for mobile commands, I learned something new.  Does this still apply in mobile web apps?

Comment: @BillHileman I would accept the answer with pleasure if it solved the problem.